# User form inputs a value, gets converted and gets automatically into another form input as a value

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have 2 form inputs, the user types in the first value, it gets automatically converted into the currency and gets into the other input form as a value.

I tried some DOM manipulation but I am not solid enough to do so.

```
   <div class="form-group">
       <input id="inpDollar" class="form-control" type="number" 
       name="dollar" placeholder="dollar">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input id="inpEuro" class="form-control" type="number" name="euro" 
       placeholder="euro">
   </div>
```

The user should fill a sign up form with input fields, 1 of them is a Dollar input. He puts let's say a value of 10 into the field. Now this 10 gets converted into Euro, so the other input field with the id inpEuro should get the value 11,08 (rounded to an integer without decimal so 11).

So in short if you type in a value into the input field the other input gets automatically filled with the converted value, to be submitted later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to listen for an [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event), then read the value from your input, multiply it and set the value of the other input.

Here is what this looks like in code:

```js
const dollarInput = document.getElementById('inpDollar')
const euroInput = document.getElementById('inpEuro')

const dollar2euro = 0.9;
const euro2dollar = 1. / dollar2euro;

dollarInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
  //if the value is empty or null
  if(!dollarInput.value) {
    euroInput.value = '';
    return;
  };
  const convertedValue = dollarInput.value * dollar2euro;
  euroInput.value = Math.round(convertedValue);
})

euroInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
  //if the value is empty or null
  if(!euroInput.value) {
    dollarInput.value = '';
    return;
  };
  const convertedValue = euroInput.value * euro2dollar;
  dollarInput.value = Math.round(convertedValue);
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
       <input id="inpDollar" class="form-control" type="number" 
       name="dollar" placeholder="dollar">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <input id="inpEuro" class="form-control" type="number" name="euro" 
   placeholder="euro">
</div>
```

This is not perfect because it does not work with inputs like `.5`, `10.`, `e` *(eulers number)* but this is more a problem with the input element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not clean but it will do.

```
<div class="form-group">
       <input id="inpDollar" class="form-control" type="number" 
       name="dollar" placeholder="dollar" onkeyup="convertToEuro()">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input id="inpEuro" class="form-control" type="number" name="euro" 
       placeholder="euro">
   </div>
```

```
<script>
function convertToEuro() {
   var usd = document.getElementById("inpDollar").value;
   //do the convert here...
   var euro = converToEuroService(usd);//get convert result
   // set the other field value
   document.getElementById("inpEuro").value = Math.round(euro);// The Math.round() function returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.
}
</script>
```

you should also catch any error if the user typed for example `12.` didn't complete the value after the decimal point.

happy coding...